# Get class wise probability scores for each Semantic class in Image Segmentation using Google's DEEPLAB V3+

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, deeplab

I am trying to extract the pixel wise probabilities for each semantic class present in an Image when performing semantic segmentation using Google's DeepLab V3+.
I am following the demo given here - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab
.

I had the following questions - 
1. How to get class wise probability scores for each Semantic class in Image Segmentation using Google's DEEPLAB V3+.
2. Also what is the threshold for each class?

Would be grateful for any help in this direction.

Thank you :)

Given link below has the graph definition for the network DeepLab V3+ I'm using - 
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/pbDVRLOaUgtZmT-rbEVmbQ

Answer (score 3):

You can get the probability by using the following:
[Deeplab code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/model.py#L203)

```
predictions[output + PROB_SUFFIX] = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

**EDIT**: The latest deeplab now provides the probabilites as well.